# Neo4J 4 + Apoc : Unable to set up injection for procedure 'Static'

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Getting the following error on neo4j server startup with the apoc plugin.
Have copied the jar to the plugins folder.

> Caused by:
> org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.ComponentInjectionException: Unable to
> set up injection for procedure 'Static', the field 'apocConfig' has
> type 'class apoc.ApocConfig' which is not a known injectable component

Neo4j version: 4.0.4

Apoc version: 4.0.0.13

What could be the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you can try upgrading to the latest neo4j and apoc versions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reviewing the installation procedure to see if you missed any steps,

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/

Also, double check the java version that neo4j is using, and check if there are any other local java environment factors specific to this install. class paths, other jars, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same issue with neo4j 4.x and custom plugin folder.
Updating custom plugin folder in neo4j config didn't work, we had to add folder (or extension) into java CP (classpath) as well.
It worked in 3.x neo4j version without adding a folder into the classpath.

Try to make sure that you have plugins folder listed in -cp and might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ilija's problem, our embedded database (using Eclipse with the Maven plugin) did not like our custom plugin folder.

Since the database was for setup and then deployment (effectively 2 separate things), we could move the database from the default Neo4j directory after it was setup.

As a test, you could delete the contents of your plugin folder and see if it works then.