# Intellij Java using Neo4j database with APOC plugin has Exception

Tags: java, intellij-idea, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm using IntelliJ to write Java program and Neo4j as my graph database. First I create graph database in Neo4j desktop(1.3.4) and then import this graph database to my project folder. However I met the issue that is

```
org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.ComponentInjectionException: Unable to set up injection for procedure `Static`, the field `apocConfig` has type `class apoc.ApocConfig` which is not a known injectable component.
```

For now I just remove the APOC plugin and it works well in my program, but it limits me to use APOC queries. I found a relevant question here: [Neo4J 4 + Apoc : Unable to set up injection for procedure 'Static'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63366803/neo4j-4-apoc-unable-to-set-up-injection-for-procedure-static) . But I don't understand the answer of Ilija Ljubicic quite well. So how should I import APOC plugin in IntelliJ so I can use it in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to follow the linked answer I added the *apoc-4.1.0.2-all.jar* to IDEA:

```
File -> Project Structure -> Libraries ->  "+" symbol -> Java
```

I'm personally getting different extra exceptions but anyway the error you pointed out has been fixed in this way.

#### UPDATE1

Importing in IDEA *apoc-4.1.0.2-core.jar* instead of *apoc-4.1.0.2-all.jar* should fix the following error message:
`APOC couln't set a URLStreamHandlerFactory...`

Comment: Hi, I just tried as you suggested but it has the error "APOC couln't set a URLStreamHandlerFactory since some other tool already did this (e.g. tomcat). This means you cannot use s3:// or hdfs:// style URLs in APOC. This is caused by a limitation of the JVM which we cannot fix. " when I run the code.

Comment: @BrandNewStory It should not be a problem but anyway try to import only the APOC core